# Quitting a job after spending ahead on a grant

Tags: funding, quitting

Let's say that I take a position at a university, and the university gives me a grant of $X for 2 years. I use the grant to buy a bunch of equipment and make some international trips, which costs me three quarters of $X. After one year, I decide to quit to take another job elsewhere, and I cannot take the grant with me as it was from the university.

What typically happens in this situation? Is it possible for the grant to get prorated ($X/2 per year), in which case I would have overspent my budget by a quarter of $X? If not, are there any other repercussions?

Comment: I assume this depends on local law and custom, but I doubt there would be any issue. The university keeps the equipment, for example. They might not be happy, of course. Not spending grant funds at a constant, even, rate is the norm, I think.

Answer (score 4):

Most grants are not given in a lump sum, but in a sequence of increments---typically 12-months increments, but sometimes shorter or longer.

It is true that when you get a chunk of money for a increment, there is typically quite a bit of flexibility in how you spend it within a phase (though some funder require notification if you go significantly "off plan").  You cannot spend more than you've been allocated, however, and asking for an increment in advance is typically either impossible or else requires negotiation and approvals from the funder.

In your hypothetical situation, then, if the funder (university or external) gave all of the money up front, and the spend plan was within contractual bounds, they really have no place to object if you happened to spend it faster than anticipated (assuming no other regulations were violated).

However... the money was never actually *yours*. It belongs to your institution in some way (probably via your department via appropriate contracting and accounting personnel), and you probably never even had the right to sign for the money.  You were just given authority over allocating its expenditure.  As such, when you leave, the remaining money (and any tangible assets, like equipment) stay in place.  The money will likely go away, since the terms of the grant specified key personnel (you) who are no longer available, but if the parting is friendly enough it may be possible for somebody else to take responsibility and the project to continue with you as a subcontract or consultant.

Reputational consequences based on the particulars of how you quit, of course, are another matter entirely.

Answer (score 2):

The situation you describe is a risk that all universities take when they hire faculty and give them startup packages/grants. Yes, sometimes it happens that people leave after only a year or two after having spent some of their startup money. Well, that’s just life. If your university gave you funds to use and you used them, and did so in good faith, the people at your university will just have to suck it up, though it’s quite possible they will be upset, and their level of upsetness will be correlated with how much money you spent, and, especially, how much money you spent when you already knew you would be leaving. E.g., being seen to spend a lot of money on frivolous things right before announcing your departure will be an obvious bad look, and a sign of bad faith and dishonesty. It is likely that you will suffer potentially significant reputational damage in such a scenario.

As for your arithmetic exercise of comparing $X/2 with three quarters of $X, I’d say it’s irrelevant. Unless explicitly stipulated otherwise, “grant for two years” (in the context of internal funding from your own university, at least in the US) generally means “here’s $x, you have two years to spend it”. There is simply no expectation that you only “earn” $X/2 with each year of work. In fact, if you leave after *two* years after spending all of the $X, and $X is a large number, then the university will likely still be somewhat upset about this, even though the arithmetic suggests this is “fair”.

Finally, one important caveat is that you should carefully read your offer letter and related documents you signed when joining and see whether there are any conditions attached to the $X grant. Sometimes startup packages have explicit conditions that you have to return part or all of the money if you leave the institution after less than a certain number of years.

Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer, and your question may have aspects that only a lawyer can answer authoritatively.